# Is there any way to implement \overrightsquigarrow? (like \overrightarrow)?

Tags: arrows, overset

I'd like to make something like '\overrightsquigarrow'. Can anybody help me with it?

`\overrightarrow{ABC}` gives us:

[image: result of \oeverightarrow{ABC}]

But, `\overset{\rightsquigarrow}{ABC}` does not stretch the arrow properly so
it can't be our solution:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Use scalerel package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Ti*k*Z solution. You can adjust many aspects of the squiggle: amplitude, post length, segment length, height, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand{\oversquiggle}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(A.text), decoration={zigzag, post=lineto, post length=2pt, segment length=3pt, amplitude=.6pt}]{
    \node[inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=2.5pt, outer sep=0pt](A){$#1$}; 
    \draw[->, decorate]([xshift=1pt]A.north west)--(A.north east);
}}

\begin{document}

$\oversquiggle{ABCDEF}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used `scalered` package. https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/scalerel/scalerel.pdf

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, scalerel}

\newcommand{\oversquigarrow}[1]{%
  \overset{\hstretch{2.5}{\rightsquigarrow\mkern-4.5mu}}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\oversquigarrow{ABC}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, scalerel, stackengine}


\newcommand{\myoversquigarrow}[1]{%
  \ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
    \stackengine{0pt}{\SavedStyle#1}{%
      \hstretch{1.35}{\scalebox{1.5}[1]{$\SavedStyle\rightsquigarrow\mkern-4.5mu$}}%
    }{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\myoversquigarrow{ABC}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It was not an exact what I wanted, but still helpful. I might need it someday. Thanks!